# Solution to a cubic-like polynomial with fractional powers

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, cubics

I wish to solve the following equation for x, but am not certain how:

$\frac{(1+x)^{1/3}}{1+x^{1/3}} = (\frac{3^{1/3}}{.691})(R/a)(p/h)^{-1/3}$

I suspect that there is some way to manipulate this into a cubic equation and solve by the usual methods, but despite much work I have not succeeded in finding any solution for x. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are $R,a, p$ and $h$? Constants?

Comment: can you tell us something  about $$R,a,p,h$$?

Comment: the solution is very large

Comment: Sorry, that was an important part that I omitted. R,a,p,h are all constants.

Answer (score 1):

Set $x^{1/3}=z\to x=z^3$

and $k=(\frac{3^{1/3}}{.691})(R/a)(p/h)^{-1/3}$

the equation becomes
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{z^3+1}}{z+1}=k$$

$$\frac{z^3+1}{(z+1)^3}=k^3$$

$$\frac{(z+1)(z^2-z+1)}{(z+1)^3}=k^3$$

$$z^2-z+1=k^3(z^2+2z+1)$$

$$z=\frac{-2 k^3-1\pm\sqrt{12 k^3-3}}{2 \left(k^3-1\right)}$$

$$x=z^3\to x=\left(\frac{-2 k^3-1\pm\sqrt{12 k^3-3}}{2 \left(k^3-1\right)}\right)^3$$

set back the value of $k$

$$x_1=\frac{0.125 \left(a^3 p \left(\sqrt{\frac{36.3703 h R^3}{a^3 p}-3}+1\right)+6.06172 h R^3\right)^3}{\left(a^3 p-3.03086 h R^3\right)^3}$$
$$x_2=-\frac{0.125 \left(a^3 p \left(\sqrt{\frac{36.3703 h R^3}{a^3 p}-3}-1\right)-6.06172 h R^3\right)^3}{\left(a^3 p-3.03086 h R^3\right)^3}$$

Comment: $p$ is already one of the parameters. You should probably use a different name.

Comment: @martycohen thank you but it looks like the OP doesn't care. I have done a lot of work to get the result. I'd like to know if it is right or wrong...

Comment: I would have stopped once I got the expression for x in terms of k.